# How to get current url for an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a if/else statement that checks the current page url for "#log_in" at the end.

On my page, when you click on log in or sign up at the top it sends you to a new page with the url "./log_in.html#log_in" or "./log_in.html#sign_up" respectively. I want my sign up box to show when the url has "#sign_up" in it and of course the same for the log in.

Here's what I got so far:

```
if (??? === "./log_in.html#log_in"){
loginButton.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
signupPage.style.visibility = "hidden";
loginPage.style.visibility = "visible";
signupButton.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
title.innerHTML = "CussFeed | Log In";
} else {
signupButton.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
loginButton.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
loginPage.style.visibility = "hidden";
signupPage.style.visibility = "visible";
title.innerHTML = "CussFeed | Sign Up";
}
```

Comment: `location.href` is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` returns the value you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href === "./log_in.html#log_in") {
    loginButton.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
    signupPage.style.visibility = "hidden";
    loginPage.style.visibility = "visible";
    signupButton.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
    title.innerHTML = "CussFeed | Log In";
} else {
    signupButton.style.backgroundColor = "#a8661f";
    loginButton.style.backgroundColor = "#d18029";
    loginPage.style.visibility = "hidden";
    signupPage.style.visibility = "visible";
    title.innerHTML = "CussFeed | Sign Up";
}
```

Use `window.location.href` in order to get current location of page

Why you are put . initially?

I think `if` condition should be like this

```
if(window.location.href === "/log_in.html#log_in")
```

Comment: the . was there because I was trouble shooting anything lmao! @Krim helped. `if (window.location.hash === "#log_in")`
looks like this now